# Need help how to use django-sitetree admin configuration

Tags: django, django-sitetree

since some week I have started to work with django. Now i would like to use **django-sitetree** to create a navigation bar through my models. But i have problems with the definition of the sitetree. For example, i want to create following menu structure:

```
maintree
|
|-- Media
|   |-- Movies
|   |   |-- Life of Pi
|   |   |-- Django unchained
```

Okay. So i have create following simple model:

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

To test sitetree i added the data set like "Life of Pi" through the django admin site.

However, now i tried to work with the gettings started documentation from https://django-sitetree.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9/quickstart.html with the modification to my models.

Inside the Django admin site i have execute following steps:

1. Home › Sitetree --> Add site tree

   - Title = maintree
   - Alias = maintree
2. Home › Sitetree › Site Trees › maintreeHome › Sitetree › Site Trees › maintree --> Add site tree item

   - Parent = no parent (------)
   - Title = Media
   - URL = /exam
3. Home › Sitetree › Site Trees › maintreeHome › Sitetree › Site Trees › maintree --> Add site tree item

   - Parent = Media
   - Title = Movies # {{movie.id}}
   - URL = movie-detailed movie.title
   - 'Additional settings': check 'URL as Pattern' has been set too

Okay the next step was to write an base.html that looks like this:

```
{% load sitetree %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>My test template</title></head>
<body>
    <b>Sitetree menu</b>
    {% sitetree_tree from "maintree" %}
    <b>Breadcrumbs</b>
    {% sitetree_breadcrumbs from "maintree" %}
</body>
</html>
```

My URLS look like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from exam.views import IndexView, DetailedMovie

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view()),
   url(r'^(?P<movie_title>\S+)/$', DetailedMovie.as_view(), name='movie-detailed'),
)
```

And the view like this:

```
class DetailedMovie(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'DetailedMovie ---------------------'
        print args
        print kwargs

        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**The Problem**

Finally my problem is that the result is different then i have expected. I see only Media and Movies # but not the Movie Data (Life of pie and Django unchained). By checking what the view got as parameter **kwargs** results: **{'movie_title': u'movie.title'}**.

So now i'm not sure what is wrong. I hope someone could help me to solve this problem or suggest me another app or method to get such a navigation tree with breadcrumbs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to pass `movie` variable into your template: i.e. if you do
`Title = Movies # {{movie.id}}` your view should return something like `render(request, 'index.html', {'movie': my_movie})`, where `my_movie` is your Movie object. That said,`get` should probably accept `movie_title` arg, as it is put in you `urlpatterns`, so that you can deduce an appropriate Movie object from it.